# How to release disk space on Mac OS from command line?

Tags: mac

I am using `rm -fr MY_FOLDER` in the terminal to delete some files on my disk. After doing this, when I run `df -h PATH`, it shows me that there is no change on `Avail` column. My Mac OS version is Sierra 10.12.6.

I am sure that I have deleted more than 10G files by `rm` command but I don't understand why the total available space didn't change. 
And I also checked the trash is empty.